# ssh percent_expand token %n not working

Tags: ssh, openssh, github, ssh-config

I'm seeing in the **ssh_config** man page and on the **openssh** website that I should be able to use a **%n token** when locating the identity file for a given host entry.

[percent_expand tokens used by OpenSSH's ssh(1) and sshd(8)](https://www.dtucker.net/openssh/percent_expand_opts.html)

GitHub allows using ssh tokens as deploy tokens but prevents you from using a token more than once on multiple repositories. So I wanted to use globbing to create a single profile regardless of how many individual project keys I had to create:

```
host github-*      
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile %d/.ssh/github/%n
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then I put a github-MyPackage public/private key pair under the `~/.ssh/github/` directory.

It finds the globbed profile and the %d works fine but if I try to do a git clone with the %n to find the Identity file name from the original command-line specified host-alias:

```
> git clone github-MyPackage:/myorganization/MyPackage.git

Cloning into 'MyPackage'...
percent_expand: unknown key %n
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This is not simply how git accesses it as it also fails with just a simple ssh command:

```
> ssh github-MyPackage
percent_expand: unknown key %n
```

I tried googling but didn't find anything on %n. Is this not fully implemented or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: IIRC not all tokens are accepted by every keyword; my `ssh_config` man page says *"IdentityAgent and IdentityFile accept the tokens %%, %d, %h, %l, %r, and %u."*

Comment: yeah, that link I included seems to suggest it should work on a IdentifyFile line so I was hoping I could use it there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your ssh version is to old, you could check with `ssh -V`.

OpenSSH_7.9p1 supports the `%n` only for some keywords (from the local installed man page):

```
Match exec
ControlPath
LocalCommand
RemoteCommand
```

I can't tell which specific version adds this token to `IdentityFile`, but it works with OpenSSH_8.9p1 for more keywords:

```
CertificateFile
ControlPath
IdentityAgent
IdentityFile
LocalForward
Match exec
RemoteCommand
RemoteForward
UserKnownHostsFile
ProxyCommand
```

Comment: that could be the case as some of these systems are on old ubuntu releases and in the process of being upgraded/replaced. But if %n is in the man page, but doesn't work in the program itself.....

Comment: @Scott It's in the manual, but not for your keyword (IdentityFile)

Comment: that makes sense. i think I found the suggestion itself online, saw support for it in the man page, but it wasn't clear it wasn't enabled in the idenity option.